# Panda/numpy map column values based on another column

Tags: python, numpy

I have input like this

```
zip    state
95648   CA
95683   CA
95648   NaN
95648   CA
95649   CA
```

I would like to fill values of state by reducing from zip.
output should be:

```
zip    state
95648   CA
95683   CA
95648   **CA**
95648   CA
95649   CA
```

For now, I have tried like this:

```
1. creating a map 
2. take a copy of zip column as zip1.
3. replacing values of zip with state
4. swap all and delete zip1
```

But looking for a better way.
Loaded values into data(as dataframe)

```
map1 = data[['zip','state']]
map1 = data.set_index('zip')['state'].to_dict()
```

print(map1) produces: {95838: 'CA', 95823: 'CA', 95815: 'CA', 95834: 'CA', 95828: 'CA'}

```
data['zip1'] = data['zip']
data = data.replace({"zip": map1})
print (data.head(10))
data['state'] = data['zip']
data['zip'] = data['zip1']
data = data.drop(['zip1'],axis=1)
print (data.head(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your map created, you can just use `pd.Series.map()`, which will take a dictionary as an argument.

```
map1 = data.set_index('zip')['state'].dropna().to_dict()
data['state'] = data['zip'].map(map1)
```

Alternatively, if you're getting all your information on zip code-state pairings from your df, you can also use the one-line

```
data['state'] = data.sort_values('state').groupby('zip')['state'].fillna(method='ffill')
```